# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined in my getTile function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get tiles based on player position and so I have to use variables in the getTile function in this section of code:

```
var level = {
    levelCols: mapArray[mapID].levelCols,
    levelRows: mapArray[mapID].levelRows,
    tileSize: mapArray[mapID].tileSize,

    tiles: mapArray[mapID].tiles,

    getTile: function(col, row) {
        return this.tiles[row][col];
    }

};
```

but when I put the following values into the function:

```
for (var c = 0; c <  vWidth; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r <  vHeight; r++) {
            var viewX = vX + c;
            var viewY = vY + r;
            var drawTile = level.getTile(viewX, viewY);
            context.drawImage(tileGraphics[drawTile], viewX * level.tileSize, viewY * level.tileSize); //drawImage(image,x,y)
        }
    }
```

I get the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined error.
I have the vX and vY variables defined globally and they have proper values but I am not sure why it is giving me the error.

Comment: It means some line of code is evaluating to `undefined[NaN]`, what line does the error point to? Have you logged each variable, object propery from that line, and made sure that they are what you think they are?

Comment: The error directs to -  return this.tiles[row][col];
The values work only if I define them within the for loops in the second part of the code. But I need to edit them elsewhere.

And the return this.tiles[row][col]; will return the tile value for the specfic input i.e. return this.tiles[4][2]; will give the tile in the 2nd col 4th row.

Comment: Try without the `this`.

Comment: I get tiles is undefined, because technically it is `level.tiles[x][y];` so the this. is needed. changing `this.tiles` to `level.tiles` still results in the error as well.

Comment: Abd what's the error for `level.tiles`?

Comment: Same error that I am reporting now.

Comment: From what I tested it should work with `return level.tiles[row][col]`. Are you sure `viewX` and `viewY` return the same value as those in your `tiles` object? What does `tiles` link to?

Comment: tiles returns the value of a section of a tile map 
(i.e. `tiles: [
            [22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22],

            [22, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,22],

            [22, 8, 8, 8, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 8,22],

            [22, 8, 8, 8, 6, 9,10, 9, 9, 9,10, 9, 6, 8,22]

        ],` ) 
so this.tiles[2][2]; would return 8 (the id for the tile in row 2 col 2)

and they should be correct values. Globally they are set to 0 but when I set them to 0 inside the for loops it works, but the values aren't editable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid and had left in a bit of code from testing that was messing things up. I have solved my issue.